# XPathCompiler.compile() throws an exception on "order by"

Tags: java, saxon

For the following code, it throws an exception. Due to the `order by`.

```
Configuration config = createEnterpriseConfiguration();
Processor processor = new Processor(config);
XPathCompiler xpath = processor.newXPathCompiler();
XPathExecutable exe = xPath.compile("for $x in /Order_1/Order_2 order by $x/@id descending, $X/@name ascending return $x");
```

It works fine for:

```
XPathExecutable exe = xPath.compile("for $x in /Order_1/Order_2 return $x");
```

The `XPathException` is:

```
Message: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: expected "return", found name "order"
Location: XPath syntax error at char 27 near {...x in /Order_1/Order_2 order...}:
```

How do I set the `order by` in this case?

Comment: How on earth is this "does not show any research effort?" I give a complete code sample. And I couldn't find anything via search about handling "order by" for the compile() call.

Comment: The expression you're attempting to compile looks more like XQuery than XPath.  See, for example, https://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200809/msg00391.html.

Comment: @LukeWoodward - As I understand it XPath 2.0 is the query part of XQuery. So that shouldn't be a problem - I think. After all, the query without the "order by" part works.

Answer (score 0):

The "order by" clause is not available in XPath, only in XQuery.

Use the XQueryCompiler instead.

XPath 3.0 does in fact have a sort() function but it's probably not capable enough for this, for example it can't handle a mix of ascending and descending keys.

Comment: Is there a sample somewhere of how best to use this? I believe the end result we want from the XQuery is a XdmValue which holds a list of XdmItem objects, one for each node that matches the query. Is that correct? And do you have an example of how best to do this with Saxon?

Comment: ps - I'm asking because the code I inherited does the compile/load/evaluate twice. Once to get a unique XPath statement, then to execute that unique statement. That strikes me as unnecessary.

Comment: There are samples of s9api use for both XPath and XQuery in the saxon-resources download which is available on both the SourceForge and saxonica.com sites.

Comment: Yes I've been through all of those I could find. None show how to just do a query and get the results. A lot seem to be built around XSLT or writing the results to a stream. Can you suggest a specific one that is what I'm trying to do - get the results in code?

Comment: I wnet to downloads (https://www.saxonica.com/download/java.xml) in case what I have is not complete. But the download there is just the program, no samples. I pulled down the EE.